# Account Settings Adapter Issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have created a account settings page that incorporates multiple options that open via fragments. However, I seem to be facing an issue that I can't resolve. I've tried multiple solutions but seem to get errors. Your help is appreciated!

When the button is clicked to open AccountSettingsActivity, the app crashes. Error included below.

Here is my code:

AccountSettingsActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.archive.pod.R;
import com.archive.pod.Utils.SectionsStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class AccountSettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  //Initializing
  private Context mContext;
  private SectionsStatePagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
  private ViewPager mViewPager;
  private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accountsettings);

    mContext = AccountSettingsActivity.this;
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    mRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relLayout1);

    //Account Settings Options List Initializer
    setupSettingsList();

    //Account Settings Options Fragment Initializer
    setupFragments();

    //Back Arrow Initialization for Navigation Back to "Profile Activity"
    ImageButton backArrow = findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
    backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
      }
    });
  }

  private void setupFragments() {
    pagerAdapter = new SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(new EditProfileFragment(), getString(R.string.editProfile)); //fragment 0
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(new LogoutFragment(), getString(R.string.logout)); // fragment 1
  }

  //Allows for the overlay to show fragment on top of account settings activity
  private void setViewPager(int fragmentNumber) {
    mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(fragmentNumber);
  }

  //All Options in Account Settings
  private void setupSettingsList() {
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lvAccountSettings);

    ArrayList < Object > options = new ArrayList < > ();
    options.add(("My Account"));
    options.add(new AccountSettingsOptions("Edit Profile", "Change your profile information.")); //fragment 0
    options.add(("Notifications"));
    options.add(new AccountSettingsOptions("Notifications", "Manage preferences for notifications.")); //fragment 1
    options.add(("Privacy Settings"));
    options.add(new AccountSettingsOptions("Privacy", "Manage your privacy settings.")); //fragment 2
    options.add(new AccountSettingsOptions("Privacy Policy", "Important for both of us.")); //fragment 3
    options.add(("More"));
    options.add(new AccountSettingsOptions("Ads", "Learn more about the ads you see.")); //fragment 4
    options.add(new AccountSettingsOptions("Support", "Get help from us and the community.")); //fragment 5
    options.add(new AccountSettingsOptions("Logout", "See you next time.")); //fragment 6

    listView.setAdapter(new AccountSettingsAdapter(this, options));

    //Navigation to fragment page
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        setViewPager(position);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

AccountSettingsAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.archive.pod.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AccountSettingsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  ArrayList < Object > list;
  private static final int OPTIONS = 0;
  private static final int HEADER = 1;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  public AccountSettingsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList < Object > list) {
    this.list = list;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (list.get(position) instanceof AccountSettingsOptions) {
      return OPTIONS;

    } else {
      return HEADER;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
  }

  /** This distinguishes between section title and list view options,
  then using switch it beings to populate the options in the list
  view with titles and descriptions */

  @Override
  public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {
      switch (getItemViewType(i)) {
        case OPTIONS:
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_accountsettings, viewGroup, false);
          break;
        case HEADER:
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_section_header_accountsettings, viewGroup, false);
          break;
      }
    }
    switch (getItemViewType(i)) {
      case OPTIONS:
        TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewTitle);
        TextView description = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewDescription);

        name.setText(((AccountSettingsOptions) list.get(i)).getName());
        description.setText(((AccountSettingsOptions) list.get(i)).getDescription());
        break;
      case HEADER:

        TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.optionListViewHeader);
        title.setText(((String) list.get(i)));
        break;
    }
    return view;
  }
}
```

AccountSettingsOptions.java

```
public class AccountSettingsOptions {
  private String name;
  private String description;

  public AccountSettingsOptions(String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

}
```

activity_accountsettings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_center_viewpager"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

        <!-- *************** Top Section ***************** -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout2">

            <include layout="@layout/snippet_top_accountsettingtoolbar"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- *************** Middle Section ***************** -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/relLayout2"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:background="@color/windowBackground">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lvAccountSettings"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:divider="@null"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp">

                </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Error:

```
E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.archive.pod, PID: 22146
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
on a null object reference
at com.archive.pod.Profile.AccountSettingsAdapter.getView(AccountSettingsAdapter.java: 78)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java: 2405)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java: 2071)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java: 797)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java: 859)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java: 1842)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java: 2202)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java: 22466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java: 6304)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java: 1103)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java: 22466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java: 6304)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java: 1103)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java: 22466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java: 6304)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java: 1183)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java: 870)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java: 889)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java: 22466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java: 6304)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java: 332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java: 270)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java: 22466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java: 6304)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java: 1829)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java: 1673)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java: 1582)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java: 22466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java: 6304)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java: 332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java: 270)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java: 22466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java: 6304)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java: 1829)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java: 1673)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java: 1582)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java: 22466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java: 6304)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java: 332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java: 270)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java: 779)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java: 22466)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java: 6304)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java: 3157)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java: 2614)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java: 1745)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java: 7768)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java: 967)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java: 791)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java: 726)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java: 952)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java: 492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 930)
```

I've included all the code, so feel free to create your own project!

Comment: can you post snippet_top_accountsettingtoolbar.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace of the exception here

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
on a null object reference
at com.archive.pod.Profile.AccountSettingsAdapter.getView(AccountSettingsAdapter.java: 78)
```

indicates the setText is being called on a TextView that doesn't exist and is null.
In AccountSettingsAdapter you are inflating either of these activities with these layouts:

R.layout.activity_accountsettings or
R.layout.listview_section_header_accountsettings

The stacktrace line number 78 suggests that these Textviews are not being found:

```
TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewTitle);
TextView description = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewDescription);
```

There are no TextViews with ids  matching one or both of R.id.listViewTitle or/and R.id.listViewDescription in the activities you are creating above.

You just need to reference corresponding views in the respective target activity. 
Try putting a breakpoint in that switch statement to confirm exactly what is happening.

fixed Issue

There is a syntax error in the listView.setOnItemClickListener ... onItemClick(AdapterView << ? > parent ...  there is an extra < left angle bracket before the wildcard.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Its strange, this actually does not show in my actual code, however after adjusting it, it did not solve my issue :(

Comment: There are some views that you haven't included above namely TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewTitle);
        TextView description = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewDescription);
Are these ok? - ie not null. And then debugging the list below does that give any insight?
        name.setText(((AccountSettingsOptions) list.get(i)).getName());
        description.setText(((AccountSettingsOptions) list.get(i)).getDescription());

Comment: So when I hover on top of the findViewById(R.id.listViewTitle); it says, findViewById may produce 'NullPointerException'. Im not sure if that may be the issue. With regards to your comment about not including some views. I'm not sure what you are referring to. Could you please potentially copy paste and adjust my code in your answer, ill copy paste and see if it makes any difference. Thank so much for your help

Comment: GOD BLESS! Haha Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell issue must be in this line in your `AccountSettingsAdapter.java`

```
case OPTIONS:
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_accountsettings, viewGroup, false);
```

are you sure you are inflating the right view for rows in the list, this layout is for the `AccountSettingsActivity.java` that contains the listview you are trying to populate. Also this layout doesn't seem contain fields like `R.id.listViewTitle` etc. as the other guy mentioned in his comments, unless you are including other views that have this in its xml.

Answer (score 0):

somehow  in AccountSettingsAdapter in below code

```
switch (getItemViewType(i)) {
  case OPTIONS:
    TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewTitle);
    TextView description = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewDescription);

    name.setText(((AccountSettingsOptions) list.get(i)).getName());
    description.setText(((AccountSettingsOptions) list.get(i)).getDescription());
    break;
  case HEADER:

    TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.optionListViewHeader);
    title.setText(((String) list.get(i)));
    break;
```

name and description not initilized successfully so therefore name cause null obejcet reference error.